# Jitsi / XMMS : always offline, unable to connect

Tags: 14.04, xmpp

I tried Jitsi, (xmpp account created trough Jitsi was successful). My user status stays always on "offline", even if I click on "online". 
An icon  wheel spins indefinitely, saying it seeks something. But nothing happens.

Here is the console return :

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connexion refusée (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connexion refusée (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connexion refusée (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connexion refusée (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:961:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle net.java.sip.communicator.plugin.propertieseditor [82]: Unable to resolve 82.0: missing requirement [82.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.lang3)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3818)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18:11:32.906 GRAVE: [57] util.UtilActivator.uncaughtException().108 An uncaught exception occurred in thread=Thread[Smack Packet Reader (0),6,main] and message was: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.certificate.CertificateServiceImpl$3.tryBuildChain(CertificateServiceImpl.java:893)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.certificate.CertificateServiceImpl$3.checkCertTrusted(CertificateServiceImpl.java:672)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.certificate.CertificateServiceImpl$3.checkServerTrusted(CertificateServiceImpl.java:643)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.jabber.ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl$HostTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl.java:2432)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1421)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:878)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:814)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:829)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:267)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody not found by org.apache.http [84]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1317)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1481)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1427)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 17 more
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had the same problem and fixed it with this steps:

- delete the ~/.jitsi (jitsi in your home directory (or create a backup if needed))
- go here https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/ and download the latest .deb available (https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/jitsi_2.5-latest_amd64.deb) and open it with the software library.
- reinstall (I didn't delete it before, just reinstall)
- Restart jitsi. Add your account YOU_ID_NAME@jit.si like describe here : jitsi.org/Documentation/SetUpJitsiAccount (add the http, not enough reputation to add the third link)